# MySql works in Php Admin,but Workbench could not detect MySql

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-workbench

I'm new at workbench and trying to use workbench with laravel,but it's not detect MySql.

Here screenshots of my my.ini
(MySql)[image]

Laravel .env screenshot ->
[image]

MySql Workbench screenshot -> [image]

[image]

On PhpAdmin MySql works fine..

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is not the same as `127.0.0.1`. Firstly, it can resolve to `::1` if IPv6 is enabled and secondly, the MySQL host specifier makes a difference between `localhost` and the loopback address.

In your case I assume you don't have a user `root@localhost` in your MySQL installation, only `root@127.0.0.1`. So, try the loopback address as host instead, to connect from MySQL Workbench.

Note: some clients, including the standard MySQL terminal automatically try both variants (`localhost` and loopback address) if the other doesn't work. MySQL Workbench does not.